# error: incompatible type for argument 1 of QTGetTimeInterval

Tags: objective-c

still have problem with this part of code:

```
@interface MYAccessMp3Tags: NSObject
{
    NSTimeInterval duration;
    NSTimeInterval currentTime;
}

-(NSTimeInterval) durationInSeconds;
-(NSTimeInterval) currentTimeInSeconds;
-(NSDictionary *) metadata;
-(NSString *) metadataDescription;
-(NSString *) loadStateDescription;

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval duration;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval currentTime;
@end



@implementation MYAccessMp3Tags;

@synthesize duration;
@synthesize currentTime;
-(NSTimeInterval)durationInSeconds 
{

    NSTimeInterval dur;

    QTGetTimeInterval([self duration], &dur);
    //error: incompatible type for argument 1 of QTGetTimeInterval
    return duration;
}

-(NSTimeInterval)currentTimeInSeconds 
{
    NSTimeInterval currTime;
    QTGetTimeInterval([self currentTime], &currTime);
    //error: incompatible type for argument 1 of QTGetTimeInterval
    return currentTime;
}
```

what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you don't want to use `[self currentTime]`. That returns the property `currentTime` you just defined in the `.h`, which is an `NSTimeInterval`. Why on earth do you feed that into `QTGetTimeInterval`?

Instead, I'm sure you'd like to get the `duration` and `currentTime` of a `QTMovie` instance.

So, suppose you have `QTMovie*movie`. Then, `[movie duration]` returns `QTTime`, not `NSTimeInverval`. This is because, historically, QuickTime originated from a different source from Cocoa/Objective-C. That's why you need a conversion function like `QTGetTimeInterval`. So,

```
QTMovie*movie= ... ;
QTTime duration=[movie duration]; 
NSTimeInterval dur;
QTGetTimeInterval(duration, &dur);
```

should work.

Comment: thanks. no "errors" in this part. is return YES? got "An uncaught exception" but maybe something is wrong in other parts of code.